# CI statistics for GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm in the process of migrating to GitHub Actions and I'm looking for some way to get statistics on my GitHub workflows like

- The average time it takes to build
- The build success rate
- The average time it takes to run tests
- How all of these values change over time

I'm not finding anything in GitHub that provides these types of insights. Is there something out there or do I have to home grow something?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like this exists in GitHub unfortunately. Insights will give you PR and merge statistics, but not build times or such. This would have to be implemented with a 3rd party tool or self-built.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you need using the `gh` cli and `awk`, like this:

```
gh run list | awk -F'\t' 'NR>1 {print $(NF-2), $(NF-1)}'
```

where:

- NR>1 remove the header
- $(NF-2) and $(NF-1) refer to the second (-1) and the third (-2) column,
  starting from the end of the table, corresponding to the ID and ELAPSED columns.

It should return something like this:

```
7874944890 3m47s
7874879462 3m59s
7874758972 5m31s
7874637425 5m24s
7874341776 7m12s
7874341567 25s
```

Starting from this, you can adapt the `awk` command corresponding to your needs, and create a simple bash script to loop over it :)